# How can I assign the values of one array to a multiple dimension array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am creating a multiple dimension array and I need to assign the column names to the array, but I keep getting the error:

> Cannot convert the value of type String to expected argument of type
>   [String]

I am new to swift, so I don't really know what to do, so here is my code:

```
var data = [[[String]]]()
var rows = 3
var columns = 3
var column_names = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Orange"]
var index1 = 0

for index1 in 0...columns{
    data[index1] = column_names[index1]
}
```

Comment: `data[index1]` is of type `[[String]]`. `column_names[index1]` is of type `String`.

Comment: Please describe what you want this to look like once it is initialized.  How is this to be used?

Comment: `data` is empty, so any attempt to index into it will crash.

Comment: And, why do you indicate that there are 3 columns but you have 4 column names?  It would make more sense for `columns = 4` and to loop `0 ..< columns`.

Comment: either `data[index1] = [[column_names[index1]]]` or `var data = [String]()`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `var data = [[[String]]]()` creates an array of arrays of arrays. you need 3 indexes if you want to be able to insert a string into it.

Assuming you only want a 2-dimensional array, you might use code like this instead:

```
var data = [[String]]()

var column_names = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Orange"]
let rows = 3
let columns = column_names.count
let empty_row = Array(repeating: "", count: columns)

data.append(column_names)
for _ in 1 ..< rows {
    data.append(empty_row)
}

print(data)
```

In the code above we create an empty 2 dimensional array. We then add an array of column names, followed by rows of empty strings.

Swift doesn't actually have a native n-dimensional array type. Instead, you create arrays that contain other arrays. Thus it's possible to create "jagged" arrays where the different sub-arrays have differing numbers of elements. In your case I'm assuming you want a 4x3 2-dimensional array, so that's what the code I wrote above creates.